# what are all the packages,plugins,dependencies need for build a ionic 2 app?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am new to ionic 2 framework and angular 2 framework.Before going to ionic 2,i were studied the basic introduction about ionic 1.

While considering ionic 1 Framework,if i am going to build a app(works on both android and ios)

**we need following things to build an app using ionic framework 1(for Example)**

- Cordova.js

Package **bower**  provides following files for ionic 1 support.

- Ionic.bundle.js
- Ionic.bundle.min.js
- Ionic.js
- Ionic.min.js
- Ionic-angular.js
- Ionic-angular.min.js

**Plugins:-**

- cordova-plugin-console
- cordova-plugin-device
- cordova-plugin-splashscreen
- cordova-plugin-statusbar
- cordova-plugin-whitelist
- ionic-plugin-keyboard

On my point of view, from my search results,i were found following for ionic 2  support.

- TypeScript
- Angular 2
- Ionic 2

Could any one tell me,what are the packages,plugins,dependencies need for build an ionic2 mobile app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First install ionic and cordova

```
>_ npm install -g ionic cordova
```

Then download one of the ionic 2 templates.

```
>_ npm ionic start testapp sidemenu --v2
```

Then just check the package.json

its all outlined here https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/setup/installation/